# Cufon confusion with hover

Tags: javascript, html, css, cufon

I am pulling my hair out currently, because Cufon is either playing up, or I'm thinking too complicated. I have a span link class, which includes text inside it. The colour of the font inside the a span should change on hover state.

```
Cufon.replace('.info-grid a span', { fontFamily: 'Vegur', hover: true, color: 'white', hoverables: { a: true, span: true } });
```

With the above code, when you open the site, the font is white. I assume it's because the above code doesn't actually set the hover state, but how can I set it? I tried setting .info-grid a:hover span class but it didn't work.

CSS...

```
.info-grid a span {
    position: relative;
    left: 10px;
    top: 80px;
    font-size: 0.94em;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    color: #009FD4;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}
.info-grid a:hover span {
    color: #fff;
    background-color: #009FD4;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="info-panel" id="info-firstteam">
    <h3>First Team</h3>

         <div class="info-grid">

         <div>
              <a href="../players/profiles/1.html" class="pic-no1">
              <p id="nametext"><span id="firstline">James</span><br><span id="secondline">Tillotson</span></p>
              </a>
         </div>

         <div>
         ...additional divs for players
         </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably wanted to setup `color` as part of `:hover` styling, right? In that case you should put this rule inside `hover` property, like this:

```
Cufon.replace('.info-grid a span', { 
  fontFamily: 'Vegur', 
  hover: {
    color: 'white'
  },
  hoverables: { a: true, span: true } 
});
```

It's said in the [**documentation**](https://github.com/sorccu/cufon/wiki/Styling), however...

```
Nesting :hover-enabled elements is unrecommended and may lead to unpredictable results.
```

... and the way I see it, this notice should be accounted in your case. So maybe it's best to depend on `:hover` state of `a` only for changing the colors, replacing the code with this:

```
Cufon.replace('.info-grid a', { 
  fontFamily: 'Vegur', 
  hover: {
    color: 'white'
  }
});
```

... as `<a>` elements are 'hoverable' by default.

Comment: It doesn't work sadly. The background is blue as it should, on hover, but the text doesn't change to white, it remains #009FD4.

Edit: What could be the alternative to an hover element in that case? I simply require it to change color and background-color on hover state.

Comment: I've been looking around and one topic seems to mention the additional use of Cufon.refresh but how would I use it in a hover state? Documentation only lists how to do it on page load.

Comment: Do you `Cufon.replace('.info-grid a')` elements as well? Or any of parents of these elements?

Comment: No actually, but I've added HTML in the post to let you know what's happening.

Comment: Ok, thanks. What if you just make a replace on `a` instead (with '.info-grid a'), getting rid of `hoverables` (= of nested :hover elements) completely?